# pandas - write to csv only if column contains certain values

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a pandas `df` that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,'hello,bye','USA','3/20/2016  7:00:17 AM'],[2,'good morning','UK','3/20/2016  7:00:20 AM']],columns=['id','text','country','datetime'])

   id          text country               datetime
0   1     hello,bye     USA  3/20/2016  7:00:17 AM
1   2  good morning      UK  3/20/2016  7:00:20 AM
```

I want to print this output to csv but only if the country column contains 'USA'.

This is what I tried:

```
if 'USA' in df.country.values:
    df.to_csv('test.csv')
```

but it prints the entire `df` to the test.csv file still.

Comment: `df[df.country == 'USA'].to_csv('test.csv')`, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple solution to your problem:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,'hello,bye','USA','3/20/2016  7:00:17 AM'],[2,'good morning','UK','3/20/2016  7:00:20 AM']],columns=['id','text','country','datetime'])

if 'USA' in df.country.tolist():
    df.to_csv('test.csv')
```

Alternatively, you can also do this by:

```
df['country'].tolist()
```

Hope this helps you :)